# Multiple Like buttons on homepage liking different subpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-like

To explain confusing title, here is the deal. I have user control which has Like button in it, and I load this User control dynamically multiple times on my homepage. When loading it dynamically I set src of like button iframe dynamically too, here is the method:

```
  public void SetLikeButton(int ID)
        {
            facebookIframe.Attributes["src"] = "//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.sample.com/subpage/" + ID.ToString()) +
                                               "&send=false&layout=box_count&width=50&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=90";

        }
```

But when I press any of Like buttons, only domain name is gets "liked" on user profile. I need it to share full path,rather than just domain name.Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't help on the iframe version but this is based on the HTML5 version at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

**Div Tag for the markup**

```
<div id="fbdiv" class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" runat="server"></div>
```

**In pageload of control**

```
fbdiv.Attributes["data-href"] = "http://www.yoursite.com";
```

If the control gets loaded multiple times add a parameter to change the URL

Comment: Thanks I'll just dump Iframes and use HTML5!